# How to use factory pattern with Autofac?

Tags: c#, autofac, factory

Currently I have the following:

```
public interface IService
{
    void Start();
}

public class FirstService : IService
{ }
```

And I resolve the service by doing:

```
using (var scope = lifetimeScope.BeginLifetimeScope())
using (var service = scope.Resolve<IService>()) 
{ }
```

This works fine. However, now I want to introduce a second service based on `IService`. So I added the following:

```
public enum ServiceType {
   First = 0, Second
}

public class SecondService: IService
{ }
```

How can I introduce the factory that takes a `ServiceType` parameter and resolves the correct service? (I can use a `switch` but maybe that is not best practice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite some time ago (so long that I don't fully remember how it works :-) I created [this snippet](https://gist.github.com/gurustron/2fe50ff8a6173b431fae66e211082f1e) which allows to create `Func<TKey, TDep>` factory using Autofac keyed registrations:

```cs
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.RegisterType<ImplOne>()
    .Keyed<IDependency>(MyTypeEnum.TypeOne)
    .SingleInstance();

builder.RegisterType<ImplTwo>()
    .Keyed<IDependency>(MyTypeEnum.TypeTwo)
    .SingleInstance();

builder.Register((c, p) =>
{
    var type = p.TypedAs<MyTypeEnum>();
    var resolve = c.Resolve<IIndex<MyTypeEnum, IDependency>>();
    return resolve[type];
});

var container = builder.Build();
var factory = container.Resolve<Func<MyTypeEnum, IDependency>>();
var dependency = factory(MyTypeEnum.TypeTwo);

public class ImplOne : IDependency {}

public class ImplTwo : IDependency {}

public interface IDependency{}

public enum MyTypeEnum
{
    TypeOne,
    TypeTwo
}
```

Comment: You might want that to be an `IIndex<MyTypeEnum, Lazy<IDependency>>` so you don't actually resolve every service type if you only need one.

Comment: @TravisIllig maybe I'm missing something - but only one seems to be resolved. [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/pWA8PW)

Comment: Oh yup that's right [we made it lazy by default.](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/blob/develop/src/Autofac/Features/Indexed/KeyedServiceIndex.cs) I forgot about that.