# Tenant specific containers in ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, autofac, multi-tenant, asp.net-core-6.0

I have multi tenant architecture build in ASP.NET Core 6, I want to create an instance of a service like MessageService which is singleton service that should be isolate for each tenant. The problem is when I did dependency injection there are 3 life time scopes which are

```
Singleton
Transient
Scope
```

For Transient and Scope it will create new instance every time request is coming, and Singleton it will create 1 time but it will mix with all tenant

My question is how can I create the instance of service that like Singleton of each tenant in asp.net core 6 using Autofac or using any other framework/Library? Or in short: I want to create tenant specific containers in ASP.NET Core 6.

Comment: Did you [read the docs on Autofac multitenant support?](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/multitenant.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build-in DI does not support [keyed dependencies/injection based on name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection-guidelines#default-service-container-replacement) so you have basically two options - switch to another container which does support it (for example [Autofac](https://autofac.org/) - and [my take](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75635209/2501279) on factories with it) or create a factory. Simple example for the second approach using `Func` factory can look something like the following (assuming tenants are static for app run, dynamic can be done in similar way with small modifications):

```cs
interface ISomeTenantService
{
    public int TenantId { get; } // possibly move to another interface for interface segregation
    public void SomeMethod();
}

class SomeTenantServiceParams
{
   // all required deps here
}

class SomeTenantService : ISomeTenantService
{
    public SomeTenantService(int tenantId, SomeTenantServiceParams p)
    {
        TenantId = tenantId;
        // flatten and assign SomeTenantServiceParams
        // ...
    }
    
    public int TenantId { get; }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

// registration:
int[] tenants = { 1, 2 }; // supported tenants
services.AddSingleton<SomeTenantServiceParams>();
foreach (var tenantId in tenants)
{
    services.AddSingleton<ISomeTenantService>(sp =>
        new SomeTenantService(tenantId, sp.GetRequiredService<SomeTenantServiceParams>()));
}

services.AddSingleton<Func<int, ISomeTenantService>>(sp =>
{
    var all = sp.GetRequiredService<IEnumerable<ISomeTenantService>>();
    var lookup = all.ToDictionary(s => s.TenantId);
    return i => lookup[i];
});
```

And then you inject the `Func<int, ISomeTenantService>` factory where needed and simply use it:

```cs
Func<int, ISomeTenantService> _factory = ...; // injected

var forFirstTenant = _factory(1);
```

**UPD**

Since .NET 8 [keyed services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection#keyed-services) are supported.

Comment: What if i have thousands of tenants do i have to iterate over each tenant to register the service?

Comment: @Kashif iterating several thousands or items to build a dictionary should not take long. Note that in case of a lot of tenants I would consider making service "stateless" and just passing it tenant info.

Comment: Ahan then its fine i was just curious about it. Thanks alot :)