# Dependency injection of One interface multiple implementations

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dependency-injection, dependencies

I have following situation:

`IMachineService with method CreateMachine()`
and I have service for every kind of machine like
`MachineServiceTypeA createMachine()` and so on...

and the same from other side I have interface for all types of machines like
`IMachine with method Start() and Stop()`

I am thinking this way -
I have to add Factory to class with Services and Factory to class Machines to be able to inject them properly with dependency injection.

I will have something like this -

```
services.AddTransient<IMachine, MachineA>();
services.AddTransient<IMachine, Machineb>();
services.AddTransient<IMachineFactory, MachineFactory>();
services.AddScoped<IMachineService, MachineAService>();
services.AddScoped<IMachineService, MachineBService>();
services.AddTransient<IMachineServiceFactory, MachineServiceFactory>();
```

This is my initial idea, but I don't thing it is good.
Could you suggest me some options please, I want to be able to create for example 5 machines of type A and 3 machines of type B all of them in same collection and to keep code simple.

Comment: You can look into switching from build-in DI to one that supports keyed(named) dependencies. For example [simple `Func<TKey, TService>` factory approach via Autofac](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75635209/2501279)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe if you use the following example of creation instances, then you will always get the last implementation of an interface:

```
services.AddTransient<IMachine, MachineA>();
services.AddTransient<IMachine, Machineb>();
services.AddTransient<IMachineFactory, MachineFactory>();
services.AddScoped<IMachineService, MachineAService>();
services.AddScoped<IMachineService, MachineBService>();
services.AddTransient<IMachineServiceFactory, MachineServiceFactory>();
```

So I believe we can create a factory and just try to get instance based on a desired type. Let me show an example.

This is the abstraction of machines:

```
public interface IMachine { }
```

And they are concrete implementations:

```
public class MachineA : IMachine
{ }

public class MachineB : IMachine
{ }
```

Then this is how abstraction of factory would look:

```
public interface IMachineFactory 
{
    IMachine GetInstanceByType(MachineType machineType);
}
```

And its concrete implementation:

```
public class MachineFactory : IMachineFactory
{
    private Dictionary<MachineType, IMachine> _machineByType;

    public MachineFactory(MachineA machineA, MachineB machineB)
    {
        _machineByType = new()
        {
            { MachineType.A, machineA },
            { MachineType.B, machineB },
        };
    }

    public IMachine GetInstanceByType(MachineType machineType) => 
        _machineByType[machineType];
}
```

And these are type of machines:

```
public enum MachineType
{
    A, B
}
```

Then instantiation of dependencies would look like this:

```
services.AddTransient<MachineA>();
services.AddTransient<MachineB>();
services.AddTransient<IMachineFactory, MachineFactory >();
```

and it is possible to use the above code like this:

```
private readonly IMachineFactory _machineFactory;

public FooController(IMachineFactory machineFactory)
{
    _machineFactory = machineFactory;
}

[HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
{
    IMachine foo = _machineFactory.GetInstanceByType(MachineType.A);
    // ... other code is omitted for the brevity
}
```

Comment: Yea I am thinking the same way... just don't want to add this extra complexity of the code with factory pattern, but if there is no other way I will do it. Because I am trying to keep code simplest as I can. Thank you for your time and your good example of how can it be implemented :) I will just wait until tomorrow and if there is no other suggestion I will mark your reply as answer.

Answer (score 1):

With .net8 you can now use Keyed injection dependency

See the documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-8.0#keyed-services

Now you can do that :

```
services.AddTransient<IMachine, MachineA>("MachineA");
services.AddTransient<IMachine, Machineb>("MachineB");
```

And in your controller

```
private readonly IMachineA _machineA;

public FooController([FromKeyedServices("MachineA")] IMachine machineA)
{
    _machineA = machineA;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont use any factory/resolver pattern,

I use `ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance`

###### 0. Extension method, to inject specific dependency

```
public static class InjectExtended {
    public static IServiceCollection AddSpecificSingleton<
        TService,
        TDependencyImplement>(
        this IServiceCollection services)
        where TService : class
        where TDependencyImplement : class
    {
        return services.AddSingleton<TService>(sp => {
            var service = sp.GetRequiredService<TDependencyImplement>();
            return (TService)ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(sp, typeof(TService), service);
        });
    }
}
```

###### 1. Test

```
public static void Test() {
    var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
      .AddSingleton<IServiceX, ServiceC>()
      .AddSingleton<ServiceA>()
      .AddSingleton<ServiceB>()
      .AddSingleton<IRepo, RepoA>()
      .AddSingleton<IPhase, PhaseA>()
      .AddSpecificSingleton<ControllerA, ServiceB>()
      .AddSpecificSingleton<ControllerB, ServiceA>()
      .AddSingleton<ControllerC>()
      .BuildServiceProvider()
    ;
    var controllerA = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ControllerA>();
    var controllerB = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ControllerB>();
    var controllerC = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ControllerC>();
    Debug.Assert(controllerA.ServiceX is ServiceB);
    Debug.Assert(controllerB.ServiceX is ServiceA);
    Debug.Assert(controllerC.ServiceX is ServiceC);

    var serviceX1 = (ServiceX)controllerA.ServiceX;
    var serviceX2 = (ServiceX)controllerB.ServiceX;
    Debug.Assert(ReferenceEquals(serviceX1.Repo, serviceX2.Repo));
}
```

###### 2. Declare controller

`ControllerX` has dependency `IServiceX`

```
public abstract class ControllerX {
    public IServiceX ServiceX { get; }
    public IPhase ThePhase { get; }

    public ControllerX(IServiceX serviceX, IPhase phase) {
        (ServiceX, ThePhase) = (serviceX, phase);
    }
}

public class ControllerA : ControllerX {
    public ControllerA(IServiceX serviceX, IPhase phase) : base(serviceX, phase) { }
}

public class ControllerB : ControllerX {
    public ControllerB(IServiceX serviceX, IPhase phase) : base(serviceX, phase) { }
}
```

###### 3. ServiceX

`ServiceX` has dependency `IRepo`

```
public interface IServiceX : IGuidId { }

public abstract class ServiceX : TypeAndId, IServiceX {
    public IRepo Repo { get; }

    public ServiceX(IRepo repo) {
        Repo = repo;
    }
}

public class ServiceA : ServiceX {
    public ServiceA(IRepo repo) : base(repo) { }
}

public class ServiceB : ServiceX {
    public ServiceB(IRepo repo) : base(repo) { }
}
```

###### 4. Repo

```
public interface IRepo : IGuidId { }

public class RepoA : TypeAndId, IRepo { }
public class RepoB : TypeAndId, IRepo { }

// phase
public interface IPhase : IGuidId { }

public class PhaseA : TypeAndId, IPhase { }
public class PhaseB : TypeAndId, IPhase { }
```

###### 5. Service & Repo have a property Id

```
public interface IGuidId {
    string Id { get; }
}

public abstract class TypeAndId : IGuidId {
    protected TypeAndId() {
        Id = $"{GetType().Name}-{Guid.NewGuid().ToString()[..7]}";
    }
    public string Id { get; }
}
```